# Access targets created with stantargets::tar_stan_mcmc

Tags: r, targets-r-package

I am trying to fit a series of models to different data subsets using the `targets`, `tarchetypes`, and `stantargets` packages. I cannot figure out how to access the targets created by `stantargets::tar_stan_mcmc`. The below will create targets like `fit_mcmc_mod1_case1` and so on. But I cannot find a way to access these targets in subsequent targets. For example, how would I call `fit_mcmc_mod1_case1$loo()` further down in the list of targets? I always get an object-not-found error when trying to name the targets generated by `stantargets::tar_stan_mcmc`.

Thanks.

```
models <- c("mod1", "mod2")

list (
  targets::tar_target(
    name = the_data_file,
    command = "data/data.zip",
    format = "file"
  ),
  targets::tar_target(
    name = the_data,
    command = get_the_data(the_data_file),
  ),
  tarchetypes::tar_map(
    values = list(case = c("case1", "case2"),
    stantargets::tar_stan_mcmc(
      name = fit,
      stan_files = file.path("stan_models", paste0(models, ".stan")),
      data = get_case_data(the_data, case),
      stdout = R.utils::nullfile(),
      stderr = R.utils::nullfile()
    )
  )
)
```